# C# Class Library DLL is not Updating properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, class-library, .net-framework-version

I Have a class library project where i am dealing with my business logic after compilation i am getting `DLL` in `bin/debug` folder.


i am using the that `DLL` in another solution by manual copy which is fine.


Again i have updated my code class library project and build-ed it and copied the `DLL` file manually to another project there is not showing my updated code or methods.
I have checked it through `ILSPY decompilation`. 

just i have added below code

```
protected string CheckDllMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            return "Test Completed";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EmergeLogWriter.WriteError("CheckDllMethod()", EventCode.EMERGE_GET, ex.ToString());
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Thanks! in advance

## Edit :

Actually We are separately maintaining class libraries in one solution and reusing the resulting DLL in multiple projects.

 
When i de-compile it through ILSPY In my environment updated code is showing but when i check them in another system or environment updated code is not showing

Comment: _"manual copy which is fine"_ - no, it's not, it causes issues like the one you see now. Anyhow, where did you copy the DLL to exactly? How do you reference it? How do you mean the method is "not showing"? You do realise it's a `protected` method, not visible publicly but only in inheriting classes?

Comment: You need to re-build the project that generates the DLL you copy.

Comment: As long as you still need to make changes to the library project, you'll be much ahead by adding that project to the solution.  That takes care of a bunch of stuff, including not needing the "manual copy" and risking copying the wrong one or forgetting to copy when you need to.  It is okay to use a project in multiple solutions, you need to go back once in a while to those other solutions anyway to verify that you did not break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably set the build property `Copy to output directory=Copy Always` but disadvantage would be that every time your dll gets updated you will have to re-copy them again. You may consider placing the dll in *GAC* in case there are multiple consumer present

> DLL in another solution by manual copy

No, instead use VS add reference and browse to the directory where dll present and add the dll to your project.

Comment: Actually We are separately maintaining class libraries in one solution  and reusing that dll in multiple projects.
When i decompile it through ILSPY In my environment they are showing  but when i check them in another system or environment  updated code is not showing

Comment: @GopiCh have you copied or referenced the newly updated dll to your solution's?